# Print name of view catching click event on Android

Tags: android

So I have a stack of views, some of them are transparent, and Im not sure which one is preventing the click event to fire on the view it is supposed to. Is there a way of printing on the terminal the name/id of the view that is catching the click event?.
(Already used the "show layout bounds" option on the developer tools, did not help me)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the tag of each view to set a distinct text and in your `OnClickListener` you could log the tag like

```
new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i("Clicked View", v.getTag())
    }
};
```

EDIT:

Note that when you have a transparent view (alpha = 0) it can still catch click events. Set a view's visibility to View.GONE to disable the `OnClickListener`

Comment: Well, that would definitely work, but I was wondering if there was an easier way. This particular view is a bit complex and setting a listener to each view would result in a lot of work

Comment: Well I'm afraid that if you want to know which view is catching the click events, it won't get much easier. You said that some of your views are transparent. By transparent, do you mean `setVisibility(View.GONE)` or `setAlpha(0)`?

Comment: They have their alpha property set to 0. They are supposed to fade away when scrolling a recyclerview. I think views with  setVisibility(View.GONE) don't get drawn at all, and thus dont catch click events (Am I right?). Anyways, I can use your approach to find out what view is blocking my way (or even set them to GONE). Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think that's what causing the problem. A view with an alpha of 0 can catch click events while a view with a visibility of View.GONE cannot. You probably have a such a view that is catching your click events. Maybe you can use a view animation (not a view property animation) to let the view fade away and when the animation is done, you can set the view's visibility to GONE

Comment: I ended up using the hierarchy viewer tool. When I tried to click my button, another view would highlight. :) I don-t know why I didnt think of it earlier. Leaving this here in case someone else finds it useful

Comment: That is also a good solution, didn't thought of it either. I will add it to my answer in someone else needs this